# How to change value of devExtreme editing popup items?

Tags: jquery, intellij-idea, editing, devextreme, dx-data-grid

> 

```
  editing: {
        mode: "popup",
        allowUpdating: true,
        allowAdding: true,
        allowDeleting: true,
        popup: {
            title: "test",
            showTitle: true,
            width: 1200,
            height: 200,
            position: {
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: window
            },
        },
        form: {
            labelLocation: "left",
            colCount: 9,
            items: [{
                colSpan:2,
                itemType: "group",
                caption: " ",
                items: [
                    {
                        dataField: "Prefix",
                    },
                    
                ]
            },{
                colSpan:2,
                itemType: "group",
                caption: " ",
                items: [
                    {
                        dataField: "Position",
                        editorOptions: {
                           onValueChanged: function(e) {
console.log($("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid('instance').option('editing').form.items[0].items[0].value);
                           }
                        },
                    },
                    
                ]
            }]}
        }
```

How can I change value in devExtreme -> dxDataGrid -> editing -> popup -> column?
When I 'click edit in datagrid and change the value of another column when I change the value of any column' is what I have to do.
I'm try to access another columns to

`console.log($("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid('instance').option('editing').form.items[0].items[0].value`,

but not working
When I try `$('[id$="Prefix"]').val("123")` , text changes but value is not passed at insert
How can I change other or certain column value / text change?

The devExtreme version was 19.2 / IDE was IntelliJ / Jquery version was 3.2.1 Please help me..

Comment: Please do not add link to external website - add code here where the problem is. Please do your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) or provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your work. Read here how to ask a [GOOD question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please check setCellValue() in Cascading Lookups https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/CascadingLookups/jQuery/Light/